# Does casting Iterables to Collection iterates over all the elements?

Tags: java, guava

Here is the source code for `Iterables.isEmpty()` ([ref](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#line.1053)):

```
public static boolean isEmpty(Iterable<?> iterable) {
    if (iterable instanceof Collection) {
      return ((Collection<?>) iterable).isEmpty();
    }
    return !iterable.iterator().hasNext();
}
```

I am wondering if `Iterables.isEmpty()` method iterates over all the elements if given `iterable` parameter is a type of `Set`, which extends `Collection`. Does casting `Iterable` to `Collection` causes full iteration? If so, why? If not, why not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am wondering if `Iterables.isEmpty()` method iterates over all the elements if given `iterable`

No: `Iterables.isEmpty()` [is implemented as `iterable.iterator().hasNext()` for non-`Collection`s](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.java#L1053). It never goes further than that first element.

> Does casting Iterable to Collection causes full iteration

No. Casting does nothing to the object, it just tells the compiler to "trust you" that it can be treated as the subclass, rather than the superclass.

From [JLS Sec 15.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16):

> A cast expression ... checks, at run time, that a reference value refers to an object whose class is compatible with a specified reference type or list of reference types.